# How do you configure airport extreme with dynamic dns?

Tags: airport

I have a domain via Namecheap. They support dynamic dns updates. I'd like to use my airport extreme (firmware 7.6.1) to do the DNS updates, anyone know how to accomplish this?

Here's the info about namecheap's dynamic dns.
http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/category.aspx/11/dynamic-dns

For what it's worth, I am willing to pay the $30 a year to use DynDNS instead, if I could get instructions for setting up the Airport Extreme.

Comment: Wow - this is a welcome change. So much better than needing to run a computer and software to always report back what the current IP is in response to pings and traceroute tracking.

Comment: Did you experience problems setting it up? The page says that you will get the details after clicking through the setup process (http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/595/11/how-to-enable-dynamic-dns-option-for-a-domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynDNS does support [Multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) (mDNS), which provides the ability to do dynamic DNS and much more. They even have [handy dandy instructions](http://dyn.com/support/airport-time-capsule-with-dynamic-dns/) for setting it up with an Airport Device. It will cost you a $30/yr standard account, though.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to pay dyndns, setup a standard dyndns host free with a purchased domain name then follow their instructions for apple airport setup, it takes 5 minutes and you get your own choice of domain name not a *.dyndns.org

Comment: My dns service provider does not support TSIG, so that is not true. My DNS service allows updates only through https and the Airport does not do that.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Duiadns, which does support Multicast DNS (mDNS) for dynamic DNS on apple routers. On their official blog there is an article with step-by-step config instructions: 
https://www.duiadns.net/running-duiadns-on-apple-router

This feature is not available for free accounts, it will cost you a $7.90/yr though.

Comment: Please check the [faq], especially the part about self-promotion.

Comment: It is one of the fewest dyn dns solutions for apple routers, the answer is matching 100% the question and your problem is that i'm selfpromoting duiadns?!

Comment: From https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion: "The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."